# How is std::vector::swap implemented?

Tags: c++, vector, swap

It occurred to me that the fastest way to copy the array from one `std::vector` to another would be to swap their pointers, as long as you don't care anymore about the vector you are swapping from. So I went looking and found `std::vector::swap`. I assume that swapping pointers is how its implemented, but I didn't see an explanation in the reference.

Comment: If you can open the header for `vector`, you could look at the implementation yourself.

Comment: Depending on how advanced in C++ knowledge the person asking is, that might be like taking a kid to the slaughterhouse when they ask how sausage is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplified, minimal vector implementation might have something like the following members to manage the data in the vector:

```
template <typename T>
class simple_vector
{
public:
    // ...

    static
    void swap(simple_vector<T>& x, simple_vector<T>& y);

private:
    T* elements;    // a pointer to the block of memory holding the elements in the vector
    size_t count;   // number of 'active' elements
    size_t allocated;   // number of elements allocated (not all of which are necessarily used at the moment)
};
```

A `swap()` operation would just swap the 'guts' of each simplified_vector, leaving all of the dynamically allocated buffers (and the elements contained in them) in place. Only the pointers to those dynamic allocations get move around:

```
template <typename T>
void simple_vector<T>::swap(simple_vector<T>& x, simple_vector<T>& y)
{
    T* tmp_elements = x.elements;
    size_t tmp_count = x.count;
    size_t tmp_allocated = x.allocated;

    x.elements = y.elements;
    x.count = y.count;
    x.allocated = y.allocated;

    y.elements = tmp_elements;
    y.count = tmp_count;
    y.allocated = tmp_allocated;
}
```

Note that the actual `std::vector` implementation might use techniques that aren't exactly the same (such as move constructing a temporary) as this simple example, but I think it conveys the general concept.

Comment: If you take `x` and `y` as parameter then it should be a non-member function

Comment: This was just a simple demonstration of the concept for how swap could work. I didn't want to add the details of how a non-member function would access the private members of the class, etc.

Comment: Ok, this is what I figured. Except, what is this about "move constructing a temporary"?

Answer (score 4):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap:

> Exchanges the contents of the container with those of other. Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements.

That seems clear enough to me.

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

I see the following with g++ 4.8.4:

```
      void
      swap(vector& __x)
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
            noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_swap())
#endif
      {
        this->_M_impl._M_swap_data(__x._M_impl);
        Alloc_traits::_S_on_swap(_M_get_Tp_allocator(),
                              __x._M_get_Tp_allocator());
      }
```

And, here's the implementation of `_Vector_impl::M_swap_data`:

```
void _M_swap_data(_Vector_impl& __x)
{
  std::swap(_M_start, __x._M_start);
  std::swap(_M_finish, __x._M_finish);
  std::swap(_M_end_of_storage, __x._M_end_of_storage);
}
```

Comment: But in the `vector` header file, `vector::swap()` is implemented using an `std::move()`.

Comment: Not sure if this snippet is much help without also seeing what is in `_M_swap_data`

Comment: @M.M, Good suggestion.