# Best way for copying large container in c++

Tags: c++, performance

I am interested in the best way regarding performance of copying large containers. Imagine that one has a vector container that stores for example 60.000.000 entries (probably long doubles) or much more values. Now, if one is solving, for example, an ODE (ordinary differential equation), it is necessary (based on the algorithm in use) to make a copy of the old values which are used for the calculation to update the new values. Following (imaginary) example:

```
// This container is inside a class (so it is initialized and stored at the memory during runtime)
vector<long double> Y(60000000,0);

// Later on in a function
void solve()
{
    for(i=0; i<iMax, ++i)
    {
        // Make a copy for the field one is solving for (depending on the algorithm in use if it is needed)
        // The following is not the best solution as we allocate and deallocate YprefIter for each
        // Iteration; imagine iMax = 1000000
        vector<long double> YprefIter = Y;
        ...

        // Do some analysis (simplified); 
        Y = something * YprefIter * something + anything

        // As YprefIter might be used somewhere else, we cannot update Y only
        Y = YprefIter + Y * whatever
        ...
    }
}
```

Sure, while taking the `vector<long double> YprefIter` before the brackets, we do not have to create and destroy the object for each iteration. This should be definitely a better choice:

```
// This container is inside a class (so it is initialized and kept)
vector<long double> Y(60000000,0);

// Later on in a function
void solve()
{
    vector<long double> YprefIter (Y.size(), 0);

    for(i=0; i<iMax, ++i)
    {
        // Make a copy for the iteration algorithm
        // Better solution as we get rid of the memory allocation and deallocation 
        YprefIter = Y;
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I am asking myself, if there are more advanced solutions around. Such as using the `move semantics` in such an example or do other things that I am not aware of stuff which would be much better in the sense of using actual developments. I would expect that my above-mentioned strategies are not state of the art. It just came into my mind that I could use two pointers while switching the pointing object for each iteration. However this is just a thought, did not test my logic here but the idea is that I do not need to copy anything; maybe a better solution and if such things work, I am sure there is already something implemented in c++ :)

```
// This container is inside a class (so it is initialized and kept)
vector<long double> Y(60000000,0);

// Later on in a function
void solve()
{
    // Create the second object
    vector<long double> YprefIter (Y.size(), 0);

    // Pointer 1 and Pointer 2
    vector<long double>* pToY = NULL;
    vector<long double>* pToYPref = NULL

    // Set pointer pToY to point to Y
    pToY = &Y;

    for(i=0; i<iMax, ++i)
    {
        // Switch the Pointer fields for each iteration
        if (i%2)
        {
            pToY = &Y;
            pToYPrefIter = &YPrefIter;
        }
        else
        {
            pToY = &YPrefIter;
            pToYPrefIter = &Y;
        }

        // Work with the pointers afterwards
        ...
    }
}
```

Any comment is appreciated. Tobi

Comment: If you need to **make a copy**, you need to make a copy.  Moving would leave the source vector empty so that wont work.  What you should try to do is find an algorithm that can work without the copy.  Benchmark both and pick the one that is fastest.

Comment: A decent compiler might be able to generate the same code for both your first examples.

Comment: There is exactly one way to copy 60000000 values: copy 60000000 values. There are no power-ups, or mushrooms, somewhere, like in video games, that makes copying X values faster than it would take otherwise. Move semantics ***avoid*** a copy in situations where one is not needed, but occurs according to pre-C++11 rules of the language. But if a copy is ***required***, move semantics can't make it go away, in a puff of smoke.

Comment: Because you are solving "ordinary differential equation", each loop new `Y` is generated, and you need the previous state and current state and update it each loop, right? So this is what your third code is trying to optimize for?

Comment: If you use a POD-struct an no container you could use memcpy. memcpy is basically the lowest api there is for copying one part of memory to another.

Comment: Also, if at all possible, make that copy as you move through the vector, rather than doing so as a separate pass.  Minimizing cache misses can speed up some code by an *order of magnitude*.  Marching through a contiguous block of memory like that is very cache friendly.  Just keep in mind that the march itself has a nontrivial cost that you should pay as few times as you can get away with.

Comment: @BlueTune Any good vector implementation will do that already if the `value_type` is trivially copyable.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for the nice feedback. Okay, a *copy* is a *copy* but as I can get out of the comments, it can be done in different ways. @KamilCuk, exactly. I was expecting that the code snipped of #3 is somehow a optimization to the two before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet is basically something like this

```
for(i=0; i<iMax, ++i)
{
    vector<long double> YprefIter = Y;
    //  ...
    Y = f(YprefIter);
    //  ...
}
```

In this case, you could simply swap the two vectors:

```
// Initialize Y_old
vector<long double> Y_old = whatever(),
                    Y;
for(i=0; i<iMax, ++i)
{
    //  ...
    Y = f(Y_old);
    //  ...
    // The swap is implemented in terms of moves, it doesn't copy the values.
    std::swap(Y_old, Y);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bob__, would it be somehow similar to the last one I mentioned? I mean in the sense of swaping the pointers (maybe the swap is doing the job here.)

Comment: @Tobi Sort of, just safer and cleaner. See e.g. [std::vector::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679165/how-is-stdvectorswap-implemented.